# How to write SCSS function to access file system?

Tags: ember.js, sass, broccolijs, node-sass

I'm using Broccoli (which uses node-sass) to compile SCSS code for an Ember project, and I'd like to create a SCSS function that reads a named file from the file system, processes it, and returns the result.

So far I haven't been able to find any references on writing a SCSS function that calls out to the file system.

How do I call out of a SCSS function to access the file system when using Broccoli?

EDIT:

I've found [this thread](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/332) about custom functions in node-sass, but it doesn't look like they're available yet.

Comment: Sass cannot.  You have to write custom functions in Ruby to do it.  I have no idea how one would do it using LibSass.

Answer (score 0):

SCSS or SASS are pre-processing languages to be used with your library (libsass) in order to generate CSS (styles).

If you are using Ember in your project then I suggest you use that to access the file system.

Ember is a Javascript Framework and it's where you should look at to combine it with, for instance, the HTML5 File API. Either that or a call to any back-end language.

Comment: Your question is not about Ember but since you asked, maybe this should help... http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/01/15/client-side-file-processing-ember-js/